# Google Cloud Armor for Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting, google-cloud-armor

I'm getting unwanted traffic in a website hosted in Firebase Hosting.

I know this because my Google Analytics instance shows countries that should not be there (we don't ship international orders). Plus, the sessions are super short (1-5 seconds).

So, I would like to:

- Set some rules to allow or deny access from certain countries that pollute my Analytics data and consume bandwith that is billed to my project in Firebase.
- Discard records from other countries in Google Analytics reports

I've explored CloudFlare and apparently I've successfully blocked unwanted traffic, can this be done using Cloud Armor?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the Google [Global Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) + [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_from_a_specific_region) instance in front of your firebase domain. You would need to deploy a new [SSL certificate on the GCLB instance](https://medium.com/@reisfeld/wildthing-i-think-i-love-you-2caa32572d24). Use the Internet Network Endpoint Group as the backend service type on the GCLB with the firebase FQDN hostname. Then, just add rules to the Cloud Armor policy. If you are only worried about Geo rules, try using the Edge Security Policy which supports IP and Geo enforcement. If you want more advanced rules, you'll need to use a Backend Security Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cloud Armor also has this kind of feature. For more information you can check [Google Cloud Armor: IP Address and Geo Filtering](https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/security-policies#example-deny-clients). From this link, it will explain options and ways on how we can block certain countries using Cloud Armor.

Let me also share this [link](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies) as a guidance on how you can configure Cloud Armor.  By the way, it is required to have a HTTPS load balancer you can see this here in [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#before_you_begin).

Here is the link for further understanding of [HTTPS Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) and on how to configure in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto)